# Executing command inside a chroot from an apache/php script

Tags: chroot

I need to unit test some bash scripts, I have setup a debian squeeze in a chroot. 
From command line I can use chroot /directory my-command, ou schroot  -d / -u root my-command, but I need to run theses commands from a PHPUnit test, runned by Apache (user www-data). 
With schroot I have this error

> E: No controlling terminal E: Authentication failed: Authentication
>   failure

with sudo chroot I have

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Better idea than me?

Comment: Solution high security inside : www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL in /etc/sudoers, and it run... I am not happy! ;-)

Comment: Try to use `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/PHPUnit-script.sh`

Comment: Right, your is better (smaller security hole) than mine :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chroot` most be run as root. So you have to split your script in two, one that is doing the unit test (myapp-unit-test.sh) and one that will be run as root (myapp-unit-test-chroot.sh).

In /etc/sudoers add:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/myapp-unit-test-chroot.sh
```

In myapp-unit-test-chroot.sh do something like:

```
chroot /new/root sudo -u test-user /path/to/myapp-unit-test.sh
```

In this way you will limit the part that is running as root.